# How to convert data type of different columns in a dataframe without using pandas or numpy functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

I'm new to python, and trying to work through some problems. I have a dataset.csv loaded to jupyter. After running through some functions I'm trying to change some columns from str to float, some from str to int and replace empty fields with None. I don't know how to apply it to the entire column. I think this code is just applying to the header, but it doesn't make sense because the actual values of the header are all strings, ie. age itself is a string, but I need the following rows of data to change the age column from str to float, or int.

I've done this:

```
[input]
new_type = []
last = str(last)
first = str(first)
sex = str(sex)
age = float(age)
sibsp = int(sibsp) 
pclass = int(pclass)
fare = float(fare)
survived = int(survived) 

#empty sting to none conversion 
res = [str(i or None) for i in new_type]

[output]
[['Braund', ' Mr. Owen Harris', 'male', '22', '1', '3', '7.25', '0'], ['Cumings', ' Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)', 'female', '38', '1', '1', '71.2833', '1'], ['Heikkinen', ' Miss. Laina', 'female', '26', '0', '3', '7.925', '1']]
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible sample of the input data? Do you have lists? Dataframes?

Comment: @mozway I'm working with the titanic dataset -https://github.com/datasciencedojo/datasets/blob/master/titanic.csv

Comment: This doesn't explain what you did. For instance `last = str(last)` doesn't mean anything if `last` is not defined.

Comment: @mozway What does it mean to define each item? This is the sol'n provided:
`data_num = []
for row in data_clean:
    new_row = []
    for i, col in enumerate(row):
        if i <= 2:
            new_row.append(col)
        else:
            if col == '':
                new_row.append(None)
            elif i == 3 or i == 6:
                new_row.append(float(col))
            else:
                new_row.append(int(col))
    data_num.append(new_row)
for i in range(6):
    print(data_num[i])`

Where are they defining each word in the string?